# DownloadString skips newline characters

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadstring

I want to import text data from Google Finance, and I use this http address as a parameter to `DownloadString` `http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=1200&p=1d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=AAPL` . However, the resulting string misses any newline characters, so it is really difficult to parse. Any ideas?

Comment: show us the code how u r downloading?

Comment: What code do you use for your downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line ends returned from the stream are `\n` opposed to the default Windows line ends `\r\n` (which is represented in `Environment.NewLine` on Windows).

Try to split on all of the possible combinations of `\r` and `\n`:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string s = wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=1200&p=1d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=AAPL");

string[] lines = s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, "\n", "\"r" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

There ARE newline characters in the file. Check it in a hex editor. They are Unix line-endings, \n (0x0A), not Windows line-endings, \r\n (0x0D 0x0A). You can feed your string to a `StringReader` and then read it line by line, and then write it line by line to somewhere else, to normalize line endings, or you can just do a replace operation.

`DownloadString` does NOT alter the downloaded contents, the only problem could be mismatched encodings.